# How do I build a method that returns an action with a constrained parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, anonymous-function

I have a common encapsulation I've been using in my controllers to handle alert message passing, exceptions, and error logging. Here is a simple version of it:

```
private void ActionHelper(Action<SpecificDbContext> DatabaseActions)
{
    try {
        DatabaseActions(db);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

This makes it so I can simply define the database interaction in an anonymous function and pass it, and it handles all the other stuff. I do have to create this ActionHelper on each controller though, since they each use a different DbContext - I'd like to generalize it.

What I would like is a method where I can pass the type (that implements DbContext) and have it return the above method. I imagine the signature would look something like this:

```
public Action<T where T : DbContext> Builder(Type type)
```

and I would use it something like this:

```
Action<SpecificDbContext> ActionHelper = Builder(typeof(SpecificDbContext));
```

How should I build this method that returns actions?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you just want:

```
public Action<T> Builder<T>() where T : DbContext
```

Then you could call it as:

```
Action<SpecificDbContext> actionHelper = Builder<SpecificDbContext>();
```

You don't need the `type` argument, as within the method you can use `typeof(T)`. But:

- You do need to make it a generic method, which means putting the type parameter after the method name
- Unlike Java, where the constraint is specified at the same place as the type parameter, in C# the constraints go at the end of the class or method declaration

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me some. I think your signature would return an Action that takes a DbContext as a parameter though, whereas I need it to return an Action that takes an Action as a parameter. I think maybe the signature needs to look like this:    


  "public static Action<Action<T>> Builder<T>() where T : DbContext"


But writing the method body is starting to hurt my head. How the heck do I get line breaks in comments?

Comment: @cspyro: Right, maybe. I was only going by the signature you'd got. Unfortunately I'm not sure I can help you write the method, other than to say that lambda expressions are probably your friends...